# How do you implement a polynomial in a LFSR? (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, prng

So I am trying to make a 8-bit PRNG using a LFSR but I am told to use a specific polynomial(X^8 + x^3 + 1). How exactly do I implement this polynomial? I need help understanding how I can design a PRNG using a LFSR.

Comment: The wikipedia item [Fibonacci LFSRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Fibonacci_LFSRs") has a small schematic for a many into one polynomial of 
    x^{16} + x^{14} + x^{13} + x^{11} + 1.  Do you think you could do the equivalent for your polynomial? An 8 bit shift register with tap offs XOR'd for feedback.  Were you also told to provide a seed?

Comment: @DavidKoontz Yes I was told to provide a seed, I am also told that that I can use the above listed polynomial OR the primitive polynomial (1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^8).

Comment: Google [How do you implement a polynomial in a LFSR](https://www.google.dk/#q=How+do+you+implement+a+polynomial+in+a+LFSR) for start.

Answer (score 1):

Xilinx wrote a good AppNote on how to implement 'pseudo random number generators' (PRNGs). The AppNote describes how to implement an LFSR based and shift register optimzed PRNG for 3..168 bits.

[Efficient Shift Registers, LFSR Counters, and Long PseudoRandom Sequence GeneratorsXilinx [XAPP 052][1996.07.07]](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write it like
feedback_polynome shows x^8 + x^3 + x^0 where x^8 is actually 7th bit,x^3 is actually 2nd bit and x^0 is always 1.

`feedback_polynome := temp_out(8-1) xor temp_out(3-1) xor temp_out(0);
temp_out <= feedback_polynome & temp_out(7 downto 1);`

p.s i hope u have found a better solution till now